# Showing app shortcut on App Switcher in iOS 9 based on geofencing like Uber does

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager, ios9, geofencing

I've noticed that Uber displays this kind of app shortcut in the App Switcher in iOS 9 with description "Arrived at home":

[image: AppSwitcher with Uber icon and custom text on the bottom]

I'd like to use similar feature in my app. Do you know how is it possible to achieve it? I can't find anything on that in the iOS 9 documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That shortcut is not displayed by Uber, it's displayed by iOS 9.

This feature is called [proactive suggestions](http://www.macrumors.com/2015/08/11/proactive-suggestions-ios-9-closer-look/). The iOS constantly monitors your activity and displays suggestions at the bottom of the App Switcher based on your usage patterns. In your case iOS saw that you usually open Uber app when you arrive at home, so it showed you a suggestion.

There doesn't seem to be a way for your app to influence this behaviour because Apple doesn't provide an API for that.